# Create object using for and yield

Tags: scala, playframework-2.0

I saw this code in an application that uses Play framework

```
val credentials : Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = for {
  apiKey <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiKey")
  apiSecret <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiSecret")
  token <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.token")
  tokenSecret <- Play.configuration.getString("twitter.token")
} yield (
  ConsumerKey(apiKey, apiSecret),
  RequestToken(token, tokenSecret)
)
```

I am not sure if I understand the reason of using for loop just to create Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] object. Why would one choose to use "for loop" to do this?

Why not this?

```
val apiKey = Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiKey")
val apiSecret = Play.configuration.getString("twitter.apiSecret")
val token = Play.configuration.getString("twitter.token")
val tokenSecret = Play.configuration.getString("twitter.token")

val tuple: (ConsumerKey, RequestToken) = (ConsumerKey(apiKey.get, apiSecret.get), RequestToken(token.get, tokenSecret.get))
val credentials2 : Option[(ConsumerKey, RequestToken)] = Option(tuple)
```

Comment: "for compression" is not for loop

Comment: @cchantep I think its comprehension and it is a loop. See this https://alvinalexander.com/scala/scala-for-comprehension-syntax-for-yield-loop-examples

Comment: `for` is for monadic composition, not loop (which is only one specific case). Have a look at the tutorial around the web first

Comment: Its a loop, its a compression, its a comprehension... no it's Super Scala :)

Answer (score 2):

For comprehension allows you to process multiple `Option` in a convenient way. Your code would fail if one of the values were `None`, but with `for` you can do as follows:

```
scala> for {a <- Some("s1"); b <- Some("s2")} yield (a, b)
res1: Option[(String, String)] = Some((s1,s2))
```

and also:

```
scala> for {a <- Some("s1"); b <- None} yield (a, b)
res2: Option[(String, Nothing)] = None
```

Just to explain this code in more detail, the code above gets translated to the following by the compiler (that's how it resolves the `Option`):

```
Some("s1").flatMap { a => Some("s2").map { b => (a, b) } }
```

Answer (score 1):

One advantage of a `for` comprehension (that's the proper terminology) is that it terminates on the first failure. If there is no `apiSecret` configured, for example, then there will be no attempt to get `token` or `tokenSecret`, and of course no call to `ConsumerKey()` or `RequestToken()`.